# Staging setup for multisite installation

Tags: multisite, development-strategy

I'd like to setup a staging instance of my multisite network and I'm not sure how best to do it.  I'm will be using version control to deploy to staging and production environments and I'd like the staging to be a full mirror of the production multisite network.

How feasible is it to set this up on a subdomain ?

staging.mydomain.com

Has anyone done this before ?

Any advice is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Right now the way we are currently using we have 3 enviroments. Development, Test, and Production. On the same server we have the 3 instances as separate sites/domains. So we have something like this. This would work best for multisite

1. domaindev.com
2. domaintest.com
3. domain.com

You need to have individual domains to be able to use the subdomain functionality of wpms

Once everything is tested on domaindev.com, we just push it to the test and so on. But if you have a current version of your site, and you want to add new features in a dev environment I would suggest replicating your live site on another domain, and maybe this script here can help you.

http://pp19dd.com/2011/01/bash-script-to-mirror-wordpress-mu-installation-into-a-sandbox/

Once you are done and test those changes, can just update your live site again.